# Only getting partial user publication in Meteor Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-velocity, meteor-jasmine

I have a client integration test to ensure my admin user can change user roles via the user management interface in my app. However, when I query for the user I want to change, the query comes back empty even though it has been created in the fixture.

```
describe('Admin users', function() {

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        Meteor.loginWithPassword('admin@gmail.com', '12345678', function(error) {
            Router.go('/users');
            Tracker.afterFlush(done);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(waitForRouter);

    afterEach(function(done) {
        Meteor.logout(function() {
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should be able to change user roles', function(done) {
        var changeUser = Meteor.users.findOne({ emails: { $elemMatch: { address: 'user@gmail.com' } } });
        console.log('changeUser: ', changeUser);
        console.log('Users: ', Meteor.users.find().fetch());
        $('#user-' + changeUser._id + '-roles').val('manage-users').change();
        expect(Roles.userIsInRole(changeUser, 'manage-users')).toBe(true);
        expect(Roles.userIsInRole(changeUser, 'edit-any')).toBe(false);
        done();
    });
});
```

This test fails with the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Here's the fixture file that creates the two users:

```
/* globals
   resetDatabase: true,
   loadDefaultFixtures: true,
*/

var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

resetDatabase = function () {
  console.log('Resetting database');

  // safety check
  if (!process.env.IS_MIRROR) {
    console.error('velocityReset is not allowed outside of a mirror. Something has gone wrong.');
    return false;
  }

  var fut = new Future();

  var collectionsRemoved = 0;
  var db = Meteor.users.find()._mongo.db;
  db.collections(function (err, collections) {

    var appCollections = _.reject(collections, function (col) {
      return col.collectionName.indexOf('velocity') === 0 ||
        col.collectionName === 'system.indexes';
    });

    _.each(appCollections, function (appCollection) {
      appCollection.remove(function (e) {
        if (e) {
          console.error('Failed removing collection', e);
          fut.return('fail: ' + e);
        }
        collectionsRemoved++;
        console.log('Removed collection');
        if (appCollections.length === collectionsRemoved) {
          console.log('Finished resetting database');
          fut['return']('success');
        }
      });
    });

  });

  return fut.wait();
};

loadDefaultFixtures = function () {
  console.log('Loading default fixtures');
  var adminId = Accounts.createUser({email: 'admin@gmail.com', password: '12345678'});
  var standardUserId = Accounts.createUser({email: 'user@gmail.com', password: '12345678'});
  console.log('Users: ', Meteor.users.find().fetch());
  console.log('Finished loading default fixtures');
};

if (process.env.IS_MIRROR) {
  resetDatabase();
  loadDefaultFixtures();
}
```

I can see the output of the fixture `console.log` in the Jasmine logs, and it shows both users. The log from the test logs `undefined` for the changeUser and an array of only the current user for the full collection fetch.

The only other problems I can imagine are the publication and the subscription. I can't see anything wrong with them, but I could be missing it. Here's the publication:

```
Meteor.publish('allUsers', function () {
  if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['manage-users'])) {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: { emails: true, roles: true, id: true}});
  } else {
    return this.ready();
  }
});
```

and the subscription:

```
subscriptions: function() {
  return [Meteor.subscribe('allUsers'), Meteor.subscribe('allRoles')];
},
```

It seems like the default Meteor users publication containing only the current user is being delivered for the test, but shouldn't waiting on the route and that route's user subscription mean that the entire user list is being published/subscribed?